# Symbol lookup error when running a binary on a different Linux host, while all the shared libraries are successfully resolved

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

I encountered a very frustrating problem. I compiled a C++ program on one Linux host, and it can run successfully even though when I run "nm -D" on it I see

U _ZTINSt3_V214error_categoryE

(And I know that this undefined symbol is from one of the shared libraries that it links to, since when I run "nm -D" on that shared library I can see the same line)

Then I copied the binary and all the shared libraries that it requires (other than the system libraries) to a different Linux host (with exactly the same distribution and version), I put all the shared libraries in exactly the same directories, and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly (which is the same on both hosts), and then I used "ldd" to verify that they are all resolved correctly. In fact, the "ldd" outputs look identical except for the addresses.

And when I run the binary on the second Linux host, I got

*binary_name*: symbol lookup error: *shared_library_name*: undefined symbol: _ZTINSt3_V214error_categoryE

So I have two questions:

First, how did the binary work on the first Linux host when "nm -D" shows this symbol to be undefined?
And second, why it fails to work on the second Linux host which is, as far as I know, identical to the first one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You probably have a different version of the library, with the same SONAME, in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it gets loaded instead of the one you think you're loading. The only way you can figure out for sure is to use `strace` when attempting to load the ***executable***, and sift through the output and verify ***exactly*** which libraries are getting loaded.

Comment: I found the issue, it is that the default libstdc++.so.6 does not have a high enough CXX_ABI version. I am still not very sure why the executable can run on the original host (which has the same default libstdc++.so.6), but I now can get it running on the second host by pointing libstdc++.so.6 to a higher version. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Well, yes, if you build something with a newer version of gcc, you can't run it on a host with an older version of gcc. `libstdc++` is tied to the exact compiler version that's installed.